MongoDB C# - How to do sorting and pagination with an array of objects on a record
I have a MongoDB with a collection: people.
[
  {
    _id: 0,
    name: "lucas",
    properties: [
      {
        Name: "powers",
        Values: [
          "fireball",
          "icebeam",
          "thunderbolt"
        ]
      },
      {
        Name: "weakness",
        Values: [
          "poison",
          "rain"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "cage",
    properties: [
      {
        Name: "powers",
        Values: [
          "flight",
          "strength",
          "fireball"
        ]
      },
      {
        Name: "weakness",
        Values: [
          "lightning",
          "ice"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "joe",
    properties: [
      {
        Name: "powers",
        Values: [
          "immortality",
          "strength",
          "flight"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "bob",
    properties: [
      {
        Name: "weakness",
        Values: [
          "cold",
          "flu",
          "no food"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

I purposely left off the "weakness" property for "joe" and "powers" from "bob", since not all people have weaknesses or powers. I'm unsure how to sort all records based on properties "powers" by their values. Assuming I have 50 heroes, I want to return all records but sorted by the properties and return it paginated.

I think it would be great if you describe or provide the desired result. 1. Sort by properties powers by length/element value ascending/descending? 2. Sort the element containing powers first?

In MongoDB query, you need to extract the powers array and its size (powersLength) before performing sorting.
After that, remove both fields so that they are not displayed in the result.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      properties: {
        $map: {
          input: "$properties",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                Values: {
                  $sortArray: {
                    input: "$$this.Values",
                    sortBy: 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      powers: {
        $getField: {
          field: "Values",
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$properties",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.Name",
                    "powers"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      powersLength: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$powers",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      powersLength: -1,
      powers: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "powers",
      "powersLength"
    ]
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

In MongoDB .NET Driver syntax, I think this is complex and possibly not achievable with full Fluent API syntax.
But you can translate the query into BsonDocument via MongoDB Compass (Export to Language feature).
var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$set",
    new BsonDocument("powers",
    new BsonDocument("$getField",
    new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "field", "Values" },
                    { "input",
    new BsonDocument("$first",
    new BsonDocument("$filter",
    new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "input", "$properties" },
                                { "cond",
    new BsonDocument("$eq",
    new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$$this.Name",
                                        "powers"
                                    }) }
                            })) }
                }))),
    new BsonDocument("$set",
    new BsonDocument("powersLength",
    new BsonDocument("$size",
    new BsonDocument("$ifNull",
    new BsonArray
                    {
                        "$powers",
                        new BsonArray()
                    })))),
    new BsonDocument("$sort",
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "powersLength", -1 },
            { "powers", 1 }
        }),
    new BsonDocument("$unset",
    new BsonArray
        {
            "powers",
            "powersLength"
        })
};

var result = await _col.Aggregate<People>(pipeline)
    .ToListAsync();

Or work with the Fluent API partially:
var setStageFirst = new BsonDocument("$set",
    new BsonDocument("powers",
        new BsonDocument("$getField",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                { "field", "Values" },
                { "input",
                    new BsonDocument("$first",
                        new BsonDocument("$filter",
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "input", "$properties" },
                                { "cond",
                                    new BsonDocument("$eq",
                                        new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            "$$this.Name",
                                            "powers"
                                        })
                                }
                            }))
                }
            })));

var setStageSecond = new BsonDocument("$set",
    new BsonDocument("powers",
        new BsonDocument("$getField",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                { "field", "Values" },
                { "input",
                    new BsonDocument("$first",
                        new BsonDocument("$filter",
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "input", "$properties" },
                                { "cond",
                                    new BsonDocument("$eq",
                                        new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            "$$this.Name",
                                            "powers"
                                        }) 
                                }
                            })) 
                }
            })));

var setStageThird = new BsonDocument("$set",
    new BsonDocument("powersLength",
        new BsonDocument("$size",
            new BsonDocument("$ifNull",
                new BsonArray
                {
                    "$powers",
                    new BsonArray()
                }))));

var sortStage = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "powersLength", -1 },
            { "powers", 1 }
        };

var unsetStage = new BsonDocument("$unset",
    new BsonArray
        {
            "powers",
            "powersLength"
        });

var result = await _col.Aggregate()
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(setStageFirst)
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(setStageSecond)
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(setStageThird)
    .Sort(sortStage)
    .AppendStage<People>(unsetStage)
    .ToListAsync();


Thank you, after playing with it in the playground, I think I am understanding this a little more. I do need more practice on mongodb querying. If I wanted to sort the powers before doing a sort on the length, would I just put a sortField before the condition?

In the $sort stage, you can customize the sequence for ordering. So you need to place the powers: 1 before powersLength: -1, to achieve the document is order by powers array first then by powersLength descending. Docs

oh I understand swapping the sequence for ascending/descending. But if I wanted to sort the values as well, would I add a sort before the condition in the first set?

Okay, based on my understanding that you want to sort the sequence in Values array?

Yes, I am seeing if that is possible and if so where would the extra sort be placed.

Should be as in this demo

Awesome, I see it's creating another set object, that handles the sort for the values itself.
